# How to Export in both in RGB and CMYK in Affinity Design?

Tags: logo, export, cmyk, rgb, affinity-designer

How do I export a logo in both CMYK and RGB in Affinity Design, provided that the Logo design starts with a template that is in CMYK? I mean when I start a new file, it asks me to choose the colour profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an Affinity Design user, however in most image editors when you export there are options to change the colour mode for output, during export.

The [Affinity Design help site](https://affinity.help/designer/en-US.lproj/index.html) under *Exporting*, within in the *Export Options Panel* section, under the *General* subheading, refers to the option for changing colour mode.

> **General settings**
>
> The following settings are available in the panel:
>
> Mode—with Selection enabled, the export options can be modified for
>   the selected export area to be different from the default export
>   option settings; Defaults, when enabled, sets the default export
>   options for new slices.
>
> Preset—sets predefined export options for a range of common file
>   formats, color modes, and bit depths. Select from the pop-up menu.
>
> File format—sets the graphics format for the exported image. Select
>   from the pop-up menu.
>
> Resampler—select which resampling method (see note below) to use for
>   the export.
>
> Embed metadata—when selected, any raster image's original metadata is
>   preserved in the exported file. If this option is off, all original
>   metadata is removed.

Answer (score 1):

Start a new RGB document and copy your layers to there via the clipboard. Select all, copy, goto the new empty RGB drawing and paste.